# Javascript / NodeJS : Passed in object seems to overwrite "self" - closure issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

My first ever Stackoverflow question (that I can remember). I'm slowly getting back into development after many years absence and experimenting with Node and Javascript.

I'm hoping this is really simple but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have 2 instances of a fairly simple javascript object. 
When I pass one instance of that object to a function on the other things fall down.

- The first time I reference a "self" value it's fine.
- I then call a function on the passed-in object.
- If I try to reference "self" again afterward, it seems that "self" has been overwritten by the passed-in object.

Here's the object source:

```
"use strict";
//simple object
module.exports.SimpleObject = function SimpleObject(inputName) {
    try{
        var self = this; //closure so we don't lose this reference in callbacks
        self.name = inputName; 

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Unable to create SimpleObject: '+err);
    }

    SimpleObject.prototype.getName = function() {
        self = this;
        return self.name;
    }

    SimpleObject.prototype.nestedOverwrite = function(anObject) {
        self = this;
        return "#1 self.name: "+self.name+" ObjectName: "+anObject.getName()+" #2 self.name: "+self.name;
    }

    return this;
}
```

---

And here's the test case:

```
var  testSimpleObjectModule = require('./simpleObject');

var o0 = new testSimpleObjectModule.SimpleObject('test0');
var o1 = new testSimpleObjectModule.SimpleObject('test1');
console.log(o0.nestedOverwrite(o1));
console.log(o1.nestedOverwrite(o0));
```

---

Here's the output I get:

```
#1 self.name: test0 ObjectName: test1 #2 self.name: test1
#1 self.name: test1 ObjectName: test0 #2 self.name: test0
```

Hopefully you can see in each case, the first call to self.name is fine, the second has lost context.

any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you put `self = this` in every method? It should only be initialized once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning functions to the prototype object that gets assigned to new `SimpleObject` *every time* the constructor is called. So the second time the constructor is called, the prototype is updated, and any previous object created using the prototype starts using the *new* function (with the new `self` value).

If you want those closures to have `self`, don't put them on the prototype, put them on `this` (more below).

But note that in the code you've quoted, there's no reason for the `self` variable. You *can* use prototype functions (which is more efficient) rather than creating functions for each instance. To do that, use `this` (without assigning it to `self`) and define the functions *outside* the constructor, like this:

```
"use strict";
//simple object
module.exports.SimpleObject = function SimpleObject(inputName) {
    this.name = inputName;
};

SimpleObject.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};

SimpleObject.prototype.nestedOverwrite = function(anObject) {
    return "#1 this.name: "+this.name+" ObjectName: "+anObject.getName()+" #2 this.name: "+this.name;
};
```

But if you're doing something with `self` that you aren't showing that means you really need it (e.g., that you can't trust the value of `this` when the functions are called &mdasdh; they're being used as callbacks/event handlers, etc.), here's how you do that:

```
"use strict";
//simple object
module.exports.SimpleObject = function SimpleObject(inputName) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = inputName; 

    self.getName = function() {
        return self.name;
    };

    self.nestedOverwrite = function(anObject) {
        return "#1 self.name: "+self.name+" ObjectName: "+anObject.getName()+" #2 self.name: "+self.name;
    };
};
```

---

Side notes:

- There's no reason to `return this` at the end of a constructor function.
- Note that we don't want to do `self = this;` in each of the functions; the whole point of using `self` is that when the function is called, you don't want to rely on `this` having the correct value. (If yoU can rely on `this` being set, then use the prototype version of the functions.)
- Never catch an exception in a constructor function and just say you couldn't do the construction, because by doing that, you allow the `new Xyz` expression to complete, and the un-initialized object is returned as the result of the expression. I've removed the `try/catch` from the above for that reason.
- I recommend *not* relying on the horror that is automatic semicolon insertion. End expressions with semicolons (including when you're assigning a function to a variable or property).

Comment: Brilliantly fast reply, thanks T.J. Problem solved already. I knew it had to be something straightforward.  much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed reply. and for picking out a bunch of bad habits I've already started to develop!

Comment: in the real code, there are plenty of cases where I'm dependent on self which was the reason I ended up going down this route in the first place.  Off to do some cleaning up! (cheers :D)

Comment: @CapnCrom: Yeah, I figured it was something like that, callbacks or event handlers, etc. :-) Glad this helped.

Comment: A few places where there's some callbacks :) Not so many event handlers yet